# Turn webcam into a CCTV?

Tags: webcam, cctv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WebCam as a security camera.](https://superuser.com/questions/79050/webcam-as-a-security-camera)

is that possible? Is there a software that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i suppose you can, at the most basic, cheap, quick and dirty way, stream from the webcam to VLC, and out to the internet - probably with SSH tunneling since you don't want to send unencrypted video over the internet, and recieve the video with another copy of VLC

Answer (score 1):

here's a tutorial for you:

**[How to use a webcam as CCTV](http://www.bobhobby.com/2008/03/02/how-to-use-a-webcam-as-cctv/)**

you can also use **[YawCam](http://www.yawcam.com/)**

Features:

> Video streaming
>
> Image snapshots
>
> Built-in webserver
>
> Motion detection
>
> Ftp-upload
>
> Text and image overlays
>
> Password protection
>
> Online announcements for communities
>
> Scheduler for online time
>
> Multi languages

Answer (score 0):

I've seen software for it before, albeit I don't remember the name offhand.  Part of it depends on the platform you're interested in.